# What happens if user want to change in-app purchase form a subscription to another?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

So I have a subscription-based model when the user can upgrade his plan from a different one (from small to large), what happens if the user changes his current in the middle of another subscription life span?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

Comment: Why the tag for [android]? I may be wrong (I'm not an Android developer), but it seems **anything** related to Apple's App Store shouldn't include Android.

Comment: @dfd I'm Asking for both platforms, Android and IOS

Comment: Honest question - again, I'm not an Android developer. How isn't this either a question regarding two *very* different platforms (are App Store rules the same here?) or else a question asking for opinions? Please, note that I haven't down-voted or voted to close. But it seems like - per your question and comment - it's at least rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can get some additional explanations in:

- https://qonversion.io/blog/ios-subscription-upgrades-downgrades-and-service-levels/
- https://blog.apphud.com/subscription-levels/
- https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/apple-subscription-notifications-are-almost-useless

In these articles you can learn about upgrades, downgrades and crossgrades, and how they are related to *service levels* and to server-to-server notifications.

In Android, you can read (or watch):

- https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8i_-H64TN8